# Does any gaming laptop with NVIDIA GPU support CUDA?

Tags: laptop, cuda, nvidia

Does any gaming laptop with NVIDIA GPU support CUDA?

Or, do I have to be careful about purchasing one?

Answer (score 1):

#### Does any gaming laptop with NVIDIA GPU support CUDA?

All 8-series family of GPUs from NVIDIA or later support CUDA. A list of GPUs that support CUDA is at [CUDA GPUs - Compute Capability | NVIDIA Developer](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)

Source: [Which GPUs support CUDA? | NVIDIA](https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2137/related/1/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xNjc5ODQxMTM3L2dlbi8xNjc5ODQxMTM3L3NpZC9mVWxVUzcwSWNBU2QxRXJIcU93a0Y0SXFZeGhFUElZNWolN0V1NnRyeVhwYjNzSjdIM0RzbnNLTk9nSkV4UjgyS2lxMjRnQ1lQZ04yZDFObU93bGVqNkdwa1Y3Wm8wWGJ6VjcyblhkcUIlN0V0Q3dxJTdFWmxOJTdFQ3JBMWtQQSUyMSUyMQ%3D%3D)